# Tokenize an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I have a text file with values like :

```
[2014-08-19 00:00:21,702] REC|SRC:923142676343|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|\nADD BBCLANDAN\n 
[2014-08-19 00:01:02,958] REC|SRC:923138824807|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD TRIXXS 
[2014-08-19 00:01:12,799] REC|SRC:923125473547|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD SahafatMedia 
[2014-08-19 00:01:32,894] REC|SRC:923142676343|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD BBCMEDIA\n\n 
[2014-08-19 00:02:42,754] REC|SRC:923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD sMs
[2014-08-19 00:01:43,753] REC|SRC:923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD RIDAsMs
```

i have raed the text file and stored it into an arraylist with the output:

output:

```
923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD RIDAsMs
923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD sMs
923125473547|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD SahafatMedia 
923138824807|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD TRIXXS 
923142676343|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD BBCMEDIA\n\n 
923142676343|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|\nADD BBCLANDAN\n 
[2014-08-19 00:01:02,958] REC|
[2014-08-19 00:01:12,799] REC|
[2014-08-19 00:01:32,894] REC|
[2014-08-19 00:01:43,753] REC|
[2014-08-19 00:02:42,754] REC|
ï»¿[2014-08-19 00:00:21,702] REC|
```

Now i want to tokenize this arraylist to display only the duplicate contact numbers which are in output e.g 923142676343 and their content which are after ADD e.g TRIXXS
I need help please ???

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class pring
{

    public static final String FILE_LOCATION = "C:/Users/DfroJaCk DB/Desktop/zongrecv.txt";

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        //Your reader
        BufferedReader in = null;
        //Where you store the Strings
        ArrayList < String > al = new ArrayList < String > ();
        try
        {
            //Open the file and give it to the reader
            in = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( FILE_LOCATION ) );
            String line;
            //As long as the file has more lines read a line at a time
            while ( ( line = in.readLine () ) != null )
            {
                //Split the line and stoe it in an array
                String [ ] splitLine = line.split ( "SRC:" );
                for ( int i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++ )
                {
                    //Add each element of the split array into an ArrayList
                    al.add ( splitLine [ i ] );
                }
            }
        //Catch your possible problems
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException fnfe )
        {
            fnfe.printStackTrace ();
        } catch ( IOException ioe )
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace ();
        }       
        //Sort your list
        Collections.sort ( al );
        for ( String s : al )
        {
            //spit it out
            System.out.println ( s );
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use java StringTokenizer. Since your arraylist is already sorted, you only have to check consecutive positions. Use | as a delimiter, get the first token for each entry that contains a number and compare it to the first token of the following entry. If they are equal, get the index of the space in the last token and print what is after it.

Be carefull to consider the case when more that 2 entries contain the same phone number, don't print them twice.

But you might rethink your approach, the way you store the Strings in the ArrayList looks pretty messy.

```
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList();
    myList.add("923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD RIDAsMs");
    myList.add("923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD sMs");
    myList.add("923125473547|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD SahafatMedia");

    Collections.sort(myList);

    System.out.println(myList.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size() - 1; i++) {

        String currentEntry = myList.get(i);
        String nextEntry = myList.get(i + 1);

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentEntry, "|");
        String currentNumber = tokenizer.nextToken();

        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(nextEntry, "|");
        String nextNumber = tokenizer.nextToken();

        String lastToken = "";

        if (currentNumber.equals(nextNumber)) {

            System.out.println(currentNumber + " duplicate");

            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

                lastToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
            }

            System.out.println("last token: " + lastToken);
            int index = lastToken.indexOf(" ");
            System.out.println("What you probably want: " + lastToken.substring(index + 1));

        }

    }
```

And the output for this would be:

```
[923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD RIDAsMs, 923119511824|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD sMs, 923125473547|DST:9900|CNT:1|OPR:zong|ADD SahafatMedia]
923119511824 duplicate
last token: ADD sMs
What you probably want: sMs
```

Comment: ok @DeiAndrei i am new to java can you tell me that how to use stringtokenizer inthis code and where to do it?

Comment: i mean where and how to check consecutive positions?

Comment: @Hassan Hameed i have added some code which should help you. But please note, if for example the number 923119511824 appears 3 times, it will be displayed twice, if it appears 4 times, it will be displayed 3 times (n-1 displays for n appearances), so you might have to skip consecutive duplicates. Keep in mind, your list is sorted :)

Comment: this is very good ,the code is easy as well to understand , but you have taken the myList.add , but if i want to read a file to do that ??

Comment: Just use the list you already have. You should only iterate through the first half of it though, since you don't have numbers in the 2nd half.

Comment: honestly telling you were really very helpful to me, i am beginner here now i am confused that should i merge the both codes how to read and how to use the list :( ? can you get me through this i would be very thankful to you Sir, @DeiAnderi ?? can you show me the full code?

Comment: Replacing your for( String s : al) loop after sorting the collection with my for loop should work. Ofc, replace myList with al . . .

Comment: Thanks alot @DeiAndrei :) you have done a great job for me :)